# SQL select statement not printing properly

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database with a select statement class that isn't working. It isn't giving me errors but it doesn't print anything but the top labels. Here is my select statement code

```
public String selectStatement() {
    try {

        PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ? FROM nickdimfans WHERE FirstName = ?");

        select.setString(1, "*");
        select.setString(2, "'Nick'");

        ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery();

        StringBuilder selectStatement = new StringBuilder();
        selectStatement.append("ID\tFirst Name\tLast Name\tEmail\n");
        while (rs.next()) {
            selectStatement.append(rs.getInt("ID"));
            selectStatement.append("\t");
            selectStatement.append(rs.getString("FirstName"));
            selectStatement.append("\t");
            selectStatement.append(rs.getString("LastName"));
            selectStatement.append("\t");
            selectStatement.append(rs.getString("Email"));
            selectStatement.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(selectStatement);

        return selectStatement.toString();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "error check selectStatement";
}
```

Comment: try this `select.setString(2, "Nick");` instead `select.setString(2, "'Nick'");`

Comment: that will not work because mysql also needs quotes around row attributes

Comment: Does java let you parameterize selection expressions, like `*`? _and I'm with @MustafaÇil on thinking needing to have explicit string delimiters in a parameterized query is unusual._

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if RS is empty before printing the headers.'

```
ResultSet rs = statement.execute();
if (rs.next()){

StringBuilder selectStatement = new StringBuilder();
        selectStatement.append("ID\tFirst Name\tLast Name\tEmail\n");
        while (rs.next()) {
            selectStatement.append(rs.getInt("ID"));
            selectStatement.append("\t");
            selectStatement.append(rs.getString("FirstName"));
            selectStatement.append("\t");
            selectStatement.append(rs.getString("LastName"));
            selectStatement.append("\t");
            selectStatement.append(rs.getString("Email"));
            selectStatement.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(selectStatement);
}
```